# How to make an Array visible while also making the other arrays hidden once clicked AS3

Tags: arrays, actionscript, properties, visible

I have a set of movieclips setup as arrays in As3. I got the code to work were once a button is clicked a movieclip show on stage; but once the user clicks on another thumbnail the previous movieclip is still on stage. What I am trying to accomplish is I want the other arrays or movieclips to become hidden once the main array or clip that the user clicks becomes visible. I know I probably need a if loop for the arrays heres my code:

```
var soles:Array = [sle1,sle2,sle3,sle4]; 
var Slbtn_arr:Array = [sole,sole2,sole3,sole4];

for (var i= 0; i < Slbtn_arr.length; i++)
{
    trace(i,Slbtn_arr[i]);

    var temp_Slbtn = Slbtn_arr[i];
    temp_Slbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, btnCl);
    temp_Slbtn.count = i;
    soles[i].visible = false;
    soles[0].visible = true;    
}

function btnCl(e)
{
    var num = e.target.count;
    trace(e.target, e.target.count, soles[e.target.count]);
    //hideAll()
    soles[num].visible = true;
}

function hideAll()
{
    for (var i= 0; i < soles.length; i++)
    {
        soles[i].visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks okay to me. What happens when you uncomment the call to hideAll() ?

Comment: Yooo that was it, It totally worked. Thanks You have been a great help that solved it.

Comment: Note that you'll get better performance if you either store the array length into a variable rather than calling it every time the loop executes or use a for each...

Comment: Ok I have another question with the above code Im creating a sort of build your own app. The user would click a thumbnail and the movieclip array will appear, I want to know how can I make it were which ever array is clicked is carried over to the next frame. So for instance I click on a thumbnail and press the next button and whichever array ive clicked on will carry over to the next frame. How is this accomplished.I want the Soles array to carry over to the next frame or step.

Comment: You can trigger it with an event upon clicking, and access the index of the array using event.selectedIndex/event.currentTarget or something.